Fetch Version compatiblity from Shopware store via composer name
Is it possible to fetch the Shopware core version compatibility of a store.shopware.com/x extension?
This would be helpful to check compatibility of extension when upgrading shopware.
Unfortunately the require fields of their composer.json files are not indicating the real compatibility.
